# How to ignore part of a file and rename the other in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I currently have a script running that replaces some specified characters of a file. I notice recently some files have similar characters in the file name. I only want to rename the part of the file name after `_`.

Example file name:

```
WB03042019_1226324201
```

My current script:

```
Get-ChildItem *4201.dat | foreach {
    Rename-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace("4201", "hfmau2")
}
```

My problem is that this produces this file name:

```
WB030hfmau29_122632hfmau2
```

Comment: What are you expecting the name to be ? Your script renames all files that ends with `2401.dat` and replaces `4201` with `hfmau2` and that's the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not show what the desired filename should be, it is unclear.

If you want to change only the '4201' at the end of the filename and after the underscore, you could use this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '<PATH TO THE FILES>' -Filter *4201.dat -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '4201$','hfmau2'), $_.Extension}
```

which produces the new filename:

> `WB03042019_122632hfmau2.dat`

If you want to change everything after the underscore and the '4201' is just to filter your files on, something like this should do it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '<PATH TO THE FILES>' -Filter *4201.dat -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '(.+_)(\w+)$','$1hfmau2'), $_.Extension}
```

which produces the new filename:

> `WB03042019_hfmau2.dat`

If this is all NOT what you want, please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55282750/edit) your question and show us what the desired new filename should be.